# Why GitHub page does not reflect the changes I made locally

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

When I use Git to push files to GitHub, command line shows it has been pushed successfully, but why the GitHub page does not reflect the commit?

[image: Screenshot of my command line]

What I use is just 3 simple command.

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Comment: GitHub is having some problems right now, just search for recent GitHub questions and you will see this.

Comment: https://status.github.com/messages

Comment: Oh I see, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

GitHubPages has defined naming standards for the repositories serving content for web pages.

```
https://github.com/<OrgName>/<orgname>.github.io
```

For Example:
https://github.com/Sauceforge/sauceforge.github.io is served at http://sauceforge.github.io

When you push your commit, GHPages copies your repository to another internal staging where where Jekyll compiles it makes it available for hosting.  This process usually takes a few minutes. If the compilation process fails for some reason you will be sent an email.

Clicking the Environments [link](https://github.com/Sauceforge/sauceforge.github.io/deployments) will also show you an activity log.

The files actually serving your site are not accessible directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but right now I think the problem occurs because GitHub is having problems.

Comment: My pleasure. Are you referring to GitHub Pages web hosting or your seeing your updated files on github.com itself?  As at 2PM AESDT, GitHub is up.

Comment: But from [here](https://status.github.com/messages), the problem still exist at least 4 min before.

Comment: I can see that also.  They have failed over and are repairing.  github.com is up.

Comment: Oh I see, I refresh my project page and now I can see the commit. It is now consistent with my locally stored project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the page that greets you when you visit a github repo on github.com it's because you need a `README.md` in the root directory of your project.

Oh and you have to `push` the changes to the remote `master` branch